# Android pdf file read permission issue one plus mobile

Tags: android, file, permissions

My CODE :

```
        File temp = new File(getCacheDir(),"temp.pdf");
        String file = "/Download/ALTO8003.pdf";
        File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),file);
        System.out.println("Is is readable "+file1.canRead());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes;
        while((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(temp,ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
        pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
```

ERROR :

2021-01-26 14:11:26.304 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 I/System.out: Is is readable false
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/ALTO8003.pdf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:159)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1.PdfList.initRenderer(PdfList.java:165)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1.PdfList.onCreate(PdfList.java:70)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7804)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1318)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3513)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.305 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.306 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7581)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.306 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
2021-01-26 14:11:26.306 19273-19273/com.sangamexportsdelhi.mtest1 W/System.err:     ... 18 more

Comment: Please put the log in a code block to preserve the lines. It unreadable now.

Comment: So you copy a a file. Please use names as source and dest instead of file1 and temp as code is unreadable now. Further you should tell what you want and what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is solved ( for now )
actually the target sdk was 30, i changed it to 26 and the code was working without error.
Here the code was reading a pdf file but got this permission issue.
file.canread() as false.